# node not listed under create content for panel page

Tags: 6, panels, nodes

I'm following this book called drupal 6 panels cookbook. With panels installed, the example in the book says to go to the Panel UI of the new panel, click on the content tab> click gear icon > click add content

Then, a windows pops up and it has a couple of links on the left side that you can click. Listitems are Activity, cTools examples, menus...

What is supposed to be listed also is 'form' and 'node' but they're missing. At first I thought it was because maybe CCK wasn't enabled but everything that has to do with the CCK module is enabled.

Honestly don't know where to look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never really found a solution, just a workaround where I went with a view to display the content.